# Navigator.push not working inside async method

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to automatically navigate to another screen after a future method inside an `async` method. But it's not working on the first-page launch. I keep getting this error.

```
**Error**
I/flutter ( 5094): Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
I/flutter ( 5094): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
I/flutter ( 5094): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.



  void getPlaceDetails(String placeId, BuildContext ctx, String type) async {
 
        try{
          await mainBloc.fetchRideEstimate(context,
              mainBloc.pickUpAddress.longitude,
              mainBloc.pickUpAddress.latitude,
              mainBloc.destinationAddress.longitude,
              mainBloc.destinationAddress.latitude).then((value){
            Navigator.pop(ctx);
         //keeps throwing an error here during first screen launch.
            Navigator.push(
                context, SlideFromLeftPageRoute(widget:
            EstimatedSummaryPage()));
          });


        }catch(e){
          print(e.toString());
        }
      }
      print((thisPlace.placeName));
  }
```

**Build Widget**

```
   isSearchingFrom?
                      Expanded(child:
                      MediaQuery.removePadding(
                        context: context,
                        removeTop: true,
                        child: ListView.separated(
                            itemBuilder: (context, index){
                              return FlatButton(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  getPlaceDetails(pickUpPredictionlist[index].placeId,
                                      _scaffoldKey.currentContext, "from");
                                },
                                child: PlacesListTile(
                                  prediction: pickUpPredictionlist[index],
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Divider(
                                height: 2,
                              );
                            },
                            itemCount: pickUpPredictionlist.length),
                      )):
                      Container(),
```

Comment: The problem is because of Navigator.pop(ctx);